# Have Thor complain about misspelled options in a Ruby command line app?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, thor

Is it possible to have Thor complain about misspelled/unrecognized command line options?

Example:

```
maid --slient  # Oops!  Misspelled.  It should give a warning or usage info.
maid --silent  # Do the behavior I programmed for the "silent" option.
```

Thor is really nice, but it isn't too helpful for me if it just ignores input it doesn't know how to handle.  Maid also has an option to specify a file of Maid rules like so:

```
maid --rules=rules.rb  # Good
maid -r rules.rb       # Short version
maid rules.rb          # Oops!  That's not valid.  It should give a warning or usage info.
```

What can I do to make Thor complain in the two cases above?

The code for the Maid gem is on GitHub at http://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got [a tweet](http://twitter.com/wycats/status/73494320480665600) from Yehuda Katz.  (Thanks again!)  Here's the solution:

```
class YourApp < Thor
  check_unknown_options!
  # ...
end
```

I tested and added it into my project.  Here's the new behavior:

```
$ maid --slient
Unknown switches '--slient'

$ maid rules.rb
Could not find task "rules.rb".
```

See [the full code on GitHub](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid/blob/master/lib/maid/app.rb).